# Generate a vector of 30 first primes in matlab

Tags: matlab, primes

i need a code in matlab that generate a vector of 30 first prime numbers. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Just `primes(113)` maybe? Or is this a homework problem of which you need to write your own code? If so, show us what you've done so far.

Comment: You could try implementing the [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: You can also do it by brute force by looping starting from `i = 2` and seeing if there is a remainder when you take the number `i` with another number `j = 2, 3, ` up to `i - 1`.

Comment: See also [`isprime`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isprime.html)

Comment: pseudocode: {2,3,...,120} \ {4,6,...,120} \ {9,12,...,120} \ {25,30,...,120} \ {49,56,...,120}. ("\" for "set-difference"; associates to the left).

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB you could do something like this.

```
x = 2; n=30;
while length(primes(x))<n
x = x+1;
end

primes(x) % primes(x) generates vector of n first prime numbers
```

If you let n=30 you should find x =113, then primes(113) returns vector of 30 first prime numbers as horchler has stated.

Comment: for n > 6, x < n(log n + log log n), according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you. This was so heplful